# Websocket workerman подключение к удаленному websocket серверу из php

Tags: workerman

Продолжаю сражаться с Workerman. Остался последний момент: как подключиться к удаленному websocket серверу и что нибудь отправить? Делаю так:

```
 $host = 'my_ws_server.ru';  // мой сервер
 $port = порт;
 $local = "http://my_ws_server.ru/ws/sender.php";  //стартующий при обращении скрипт
 $data = 'hello world!';  //что шлем

 $head = "GET / HTTP/1.1"."\r\n".
 "Upgrade: WebSocket"."\r\n".
 "Connection: Upgrade"."\r\n".
 "Origin: $local"."\r\n".
 "Host: $host"."\r\n".
 "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n"."\r\n";

 $sock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);

 fwrite($sock, $head ) or die('error:'.$errno.':'.$errstr);
 $headers = fread($sock, 2000);

 /* В этом моменте сбрасываю в файл полученные заголовки, ну чисто глянуть что там, 
а там вот что: 
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
<b>400 Bad Request</b><br>Sec-WebSocket-Key not found.<br>This is a 
WebSocket service and can not be accessed via HTTP.<br>See <a 
href="http://wiki.workerman.net/Error1">http://wiki.workerman.net/Error1</a> 
for detail. 
*/
fclose($sock);
```

Как же мне все таки подключиться из PHP скрипта к моему удаленному Workerman?

Comment: покажите код Вашего сервера

Comment: код сервера - это код Workerman :) весь мой код - это то что я написал выше. кстати, я понял о чем речь идет в ошибке, в Вики посмотрел,Ю ему ключ нужен, заголовок должен выглядеть так `GET /chat HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://example.com`

Comment: сервер мне правильно ответил, вижу в логе, теперь надо понять как мне Origin этот прилепить, чтобы стартовал мой скрипт после handshake. fwrite что то не отрабатывает

Comment: Вы не поняли. подразумевается скрипт запуска Workerman. Вы же отправляете сообщение на запущенный Workerman.

Comment: ну тут я пошел таким путем: есть условно говоря скрипт sender.php, он лежит вместе с workerman. Через $_GET или в браузере по http:// передаю на sender.php user=Petr, message=Hello либо же с удаленного php через curl инициализирую запуск sender.php с такими же параметрами, все как бы работает норм. Но это все работает потому что js уже установил коннетк

Comment: Прошу прощения, беру таймаут, вроде как вырисовывается решение...